# Best practice for running container images as another user

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I'm using Kubernetes and would like to run a container as a non-root user.

If I'm writing my own Dockerfile, I can `useradd`, `chmod 777`, and run with docker `--user <username>`.

But in some cases, the list of files that need to be `chmod`'ed may be long and unknown, becoming a tedious process, and it can change over time, and cause errors that are only found at runtime.

Is there a best practice? How would you handle folders like `/var/log` and `/var/run`?
One option is to touch/mkdir and use `setfacl`.

The easiest is just to `chmod 777 -R /var/log`.

But would that give the container `777` access on the host as well? How is it mapped, when the container has one set of permissions, but the host has another?

Answer (score 1):

Using `chmod 777` is basically never the right solution. Figure out how to set your permissions correctly. Permissions should almost always be least possible that accomplish your goal.

How you do that is heavily depends on the context of the specific image, and what software you are running.

> But would that give the container 777 access on the host as well?

Depends on if the path you are changing the permissions is or will be a bind bind mount.

Answer (score 0):

I found this relevant to my own question:

> Overlay file system mounts up a lower directory and then attaches an upper directory to the merged mount point. When a process writes to a new file to the merged directory, the new file gets written to the upper directory. When a process modifies an existing file in the lower directory, the kernel copies-up the file from the lower directory to the upper directory and allows the process to modify the file in the upper directory.

So `chown` on an overlay (upper) directory should have no effect on the host (lower) directory.

But I guess `chmod 777` could allow other users to access the overlay filesystem on the host.